# cross section of torus

Tags: geometry, solid-of-revolution, cross-sections

Is there any particular name for the plane revolved about an external axis to form a torus? I was thinking of "cross section," but that could be taken as a vertical plane cutting the whole torus in two to produce dual planes or a horizontal plane cutting the torus in two to produce an annulus. I'm thinking of a cross section formed by a vertical plane extending outward from the center of the torus and cutting through it on only one side.

Comment: The term "generator" may apply to the *circle* that rotates around the axis to form a torus, in the same sense that a "generator of a cone" is a line that rotates around to trace-out the surface. It's hard to verify this kind of thing with a web search for "torus generator", however. :/

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that cross-section is perfectly valid for *any* intersecting plane hitting the torus. Even so I admit, like you already did, that this notion mentally might be wrongly understood to meen the orthogonal case with the axis of the torus being fully included within the cutting plane. Therefore I'd advise you to take refuge to according adjectives in addition. E.g. non-symmetrically alligned / affine / non-orthogonal / off-centric - or the like.

--- rk